# @ControllerAdvice doesn't handle more specific exception

Tags: java, exception

There's a piece of code that throws a exception:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: cn.dev33.satoken.exception.NotLoginException: Invalid Token：ldxutBDDKBEDa9LjWNTKLFbW7g7B86qU`.
And then it goes into `handleRuntimeException` rather than `returnNotLoginException` method.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Primary
public class MyLockKeyBuilder extends DefaultLockKeyBuilder {

  @Override
  public String buildKey(MethodInvocation invocation, String[] definitionKeys) {
    String key = super.buildKey(invocation, definitionKeys);
    Object loginId = StpUtil.getLoginId(); // throw a exception
    key = loginId.toString();
    return key;
  }
}
```

```
    @ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.test")
    @Slf4j
    public class GraceExceptionHandlerApp {
       @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
       @ExceptionHandler(value = NotLoginException.class)
       @ResponseBody
        public JSONObject returnNotLoginException(NotLoginException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          String message = e.getMessage();
          ResponseStatusEnum failed = ResponseStatusEnum.UNAUTHORIZED;
          failed.setMsg(message);
          return ZheliResult.exception(failed);
        }

       @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
       @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
       @ResponseBody
       public JSONObject handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException e, HttpServletRequest request)
       {
         String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
         return ZheliResult.errorCustom(ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED);
       }
    ...
}
```

I want it goes into the `returnNotLoginException` method, could anyone tell me how to do it?

---

UPDATE

I've made a mistake, really, for I didn't offer enough info.

Missed Info:

1. My application was a distributed system and services to invoke another via rpc communication. `MyLockKeyBuilder`  was on the provider service, and `GraceExceptionHandlerApp`  was on the comsumer service.
2. When the provider service throw a exception and before it being passed to the comsumer sevice, it would be filter by a Filter called `ExceptionFilter`, which wrap the exception that the comsumer side doesn't recognize  to `RuntimeException`, to avoid serialization issue.

Finally I solved this problem by rewritting the `ExceptionFilter` class to  allow  original `NotLoginException` to be passed to the consumer side.

Answer (score 0):

`NotLoginException` is the inner exception of your `RuntimeException`. If you want your controller advice to handle it, catch the RuntimeException buildKey and throw its inner exception.

Comment: catch RuntimeException and throw its inner exception doesn't work

Comment: Did you try it ? Or because its an unchecked exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cn.dev33.satoken.exception.NotLoginException: Invalid Token：
```

Your exception type is `java.lang.RuntimeException` & cause of exception is `NotLoginException`.

Controller advice will invoke respective method when type of exception matches & not cause of exception.

So if you really want to invoke `returnNotLoginException`, then you need to throw `NotLoginException` in your logic instead of throwing `RuntimeException`.

Something like:

```
..
throw new NotLoginException("exception"); //in your StpUtil.getLoginId();
..
```